# What is the skill of "remembering all the variables involved in a situation" called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What is the skill of being able to recall to mind all of the variables involved in a situation called?

For instance, if I have to get together a bunch of documents for a lawyer, and he asks for all of my joint bank accounts and if there are a lot of them, if I can remember all of them without missing any and without having to reference anything, what is the skill called that is used for this?

Comment: It's called "spooky".

Comment: Good personal organisation, maintaining a filing system and making notes. There is no magic involved. The Germans are brilliant at it. It is just a case of having the right attitude of mind.

Comment: *"contextual awareness"*

Comment: There is the idiom "details man", though that usually refers to someone who is good at taking care of the details of carrying out a task, vs just having command of the information.

Answer (score 1):

I like *[Photographic memory:](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/photographic-memory)*

> noun
>
> a memory that is able to retain facts, appearances, etc, in precise
>   detail, often after only a very short view of or exposure to them
>
> ⇒ He had a photographic memory for maps.

There seems to be some [scientific dispute](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/i-developed-what-appears-to-be-a-ph/) about the value of the descriptive term "photographic memory:"

> The intuitive notion of a “photographic” memory is that it is just
>   like a photograph: you can retrieve it from your memory at will and
>   examine it in detail, zooming in on different parts. But a true
>   photographic memory in this sense has never been proved to exist.

So more technically [Eidetic memory:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidetic_memory)

> an ability to recall images, sounds, or objects in memory after
>   only a few instants of exposure, with high precision for some time
>   after exposure

***Mnemonic Retention*** is probably the safest, except it has been coopted by EQ, a cybergame:

***[Mnemonic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mnemonic)***:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1 Aiding or designed to aid the memory.

[***Retention***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/retention):

> The fact of keeping something in one’s memory:

Everyone has a mnemonic system to help remember important things, but some people have a much more powerful and finely tuned system:

> Most of us do have a kind of photographic memory, in that most
>   people's memory for visual material is much better and more detailed
>   than our recall of most other kinds of material. For instance, most of
>   us remember a face much more easily than the name associated with that
>   face. But this isn't really a photographic memory; it just shows us
>   the normal difference between types of memory...
>
> So how does an exceptional, perhaps photographic, memory come to be?
>   It depends on a slew of factors, including our genetics, brain
>   development and experiences. It is difficult to disentangle memory
>   abilities that appear early from those cultivated through interest and
>   training. Most people who have exhibited truly extraordinary memories
>   in some domain have seemed to possess them all their lives and honed
>   them further through practice.

---

www.oxforddictionaries.com

www.collinsdictionary.com

www.scientificamerican.com

en.wikipedia.org

Answer (score 1):

Somebody who understands a situation well and knows all the relevant information [like the back of their hand](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/know-sth-like-the-back-of-your-hand) is often described as **on top of their brief**, particularly if it's in a professional context (I can't find an authoritative source, but I think the phrase originates with the idea of a [barrister's brief](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/brief)).

> He was a minister utterly **on top of his brief**, with an extraordinary knowledge of educational research and statistics. ([The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/politics/2014/jul/15/michael-gove-controversial-influential-education-secretary), 15 July 2014)
>
> Even without her special access, she learns much simply by **doing her homework**. She is always, in a phrase used about barristers, "**on top of her brief**."  (Michael Paterson (2012), *A Brief History of the Private Life of Elizabeth II*)
>
> If that were true, it is possibly as a result of May's determination to be **on top of her brief**. "She's such a **details person**, she does actually read every submission back to front," says a former colleague. "Nothing slips through. I've had civil servants say, 'She knows more than I do.'"  ([The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/politics/2014/jul/27/theresa-may-profile-beyond-the-public-image), 27 July 2014)

As mentioned in the comments, you might try "**details person**" to describe the *character trait* of a person with this skill, whereas for the *task* of doing the necessary preliminary work and research, consider saying that someone has **done his homework**.

There's also **on top of the details** (which I think also applies in non-professional situations) and **in command of the facts**.